# Setting default value in dropdown after changing element jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I apologize in advance if this question/issue was brought up or asked. I did not find one of this type.

On button click, I would like to change the data field into a dropdown list that defaults to the value that was present before the change.

```js
$("#edit").on("click", function() {
  let food = $("#food");
  let foodValue = food.attr("data-food-value");

  food.html(`<select>
                     <option value="1">Fries</option>
                     <option value="2">Burger</option>
                     <option value="3">Pizza</option>
                  </select>`);

  $(`#food select option[value="${foodValue}"]`).attr("selected", true);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>Favorite Food</th>
      <td id="food" data-food-value="3">Pizza</td>
    </tr>
    <tbody>
</table>

<button id="edit">Edit</button>
```

I want it to default to Pizza on button click, but it defaults to Fries. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: So you want to replace the `text` in your food div with your `select`?

Comment: The code already does what you want. I fixed the missing `()` after `function`, but it wouldn't have run at all without that.

Comment: But if you always want Pizza selected, than just change `<option value="3">` to `<option value="3" selected="selected">`

Comment: Thank you Barmar. It works.